# Getting the Run-time error 13, Type mismatch when i execute

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I wonder if someone could help with my code. I'm not used to VBA. So, I have a worksheet that goes into my folders to get information from other excels and post in my worksheet. I have a function name ThisWorkbook.Autofill where I can write the name and the number of my product and click Autofill after, and it posts all my information.
When i run it line by line, the error comes at this line.

```
filePath = "Y:\Production - opérations\meunerie\MEUNIER\Résultats Tests de Moutures " & _
                                dossier & _
                                "\[" & course & "-" & fichier & ".xlsm]"
```

Full code:

```
Dim tableRow As Range

Dim course, recette, dossier, fichier, filePath As String

Dim locArray, dynCol As Variant

Private Const RECAP = "Récap"

Private Const RESULTAT = "Résultats"


Sub AutoFill()
    locArray = Array( _
        Array(RESULTAT, "$S$1"), Array(RESULTAT, "$O$1"), Array(RESULTAT, "$X$1"), Array(RECAP, "$V$12"), Array(RECAP, "$W$12"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$X$12"), Array(RECAP, "$Y$12"), Array(RECAP, "$V$17"), Array(RECAP, "$W$17"), Array(RECAP, "$X$17"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$Y$17"), Array(RECAP, "$V$22"), Array(RECAP, "$W$22"), Array(RECAP, "$X$22"), Array(RECAP, "$Y$22"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$V$27"), Array(RECAP, "$W$27"), Array(RECAP, "$X$27"), Array(RECAP, "$Y$27"), Array(RECAP, "$V$32"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$W$32"), Array(RECAP, "$X$32"), Array(RECAP, "$Y$32"), Array(RECAP, "$V$37"), Array(RECAP, "$W$37"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$X$37"), Array(RECAP, "$Y$37"), Array(RECAP, "$V$42"), Array(RECAP, "$W$42"), Array(RECAP, "$X$42"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$Y$42"), Array(RECAP, "$AA$12"), Array(RECAP, "$AB$12"), Array(RECAP, "$AC$12"), Array(RECAP, "$AD$12"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AA$22"), Array(RECAP, "$AB$22"), Array(RECAP, "$AC$22"), Array(RECAP, "$AD$22"), Array(RECAP, "$AA$27"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AB$27"), Array(RECAP, "$AC$27"), Array(RECAP, "$AD$27"), Array(RECAP, "$AA$32"), Array(RECAP, "$AB$32"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AC$32"), Array(RECAP, "$AD$32"), Array(RECAP, "$AA$42"), Array(RECAP, "$AB$42"), Array(RECAP, "$AC$42"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AD$42"), Array(RECAP, "$AF$12"), Array(RECAP, "$AG$12"), Array(RECAP, "$AH$12"), Array(RECAP, "$AI$12"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AF$17"), Array(RECAP, "$AG$17"), Array(RECAP, "$AH$17"), Array(RECAP, "$AI$17"), Array(RECAP, "$AF$22"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AG$22"), Array(RECAP, "$AH$22"), Array(RECAP, "$AI$22"), Array(RECAP, "$AF$27"), Array(RECAP, "$AG$27"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AH$27"), Array(RECAP, "$AI$27"), Array(RECAP, "$AI$52"), Array(RECAP, "$AI$54"), Array(RESULTAT, "$K$1"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$W$54"), Array(RECAP, "$X$54"), Array(RECAP, "$Y$54"), Array(RECAP, "$Z$54"), Array(RECAP, "$AA$54"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AB$54"), Array(RECAP, "$AC$54"), Array(RECAP, "$W$56"), Array(RECAP, "$X$56"), Array(RECAP, "$Y$56"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$Z$56"), Array(RECAP, "$AA$56"), Array(RECAP, "$AB$56"), Array(RECAP, "$AC$56"), Array(RECAP, "$AD$55/1000"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AF$32"), Array(RECAP, "$AG$32"), Array(RECAP, "$AH$32"), Array(RECAP, "$AI$32"), Array(RECAP, "$AH$42"), _
        Array(RECAP, "$AH$45"), Array(RECAP, "$AH$46"), Array(RECAP, "$AH$47"), Array(RECAP, "$AH$48") _
    )
    
    For Each tableRow In [Table1].Rows
        If tableRow.Row <> 3 Then
            course = tableRow.Columns(1).Value
            recette = tableRow.Columns(2).Value
            dossier = tableRow.Columns(3).Value
            fichier = tableRow.Columns(4).Value
            filePath = "Y:\Production - opérations\meunerie\MEUNIER\Résultats Tests de Moutures " & _
                                    dossier & _
                                    "\[" & course & "-" & fichier & ".xlsm]"
            
            i = 5
            For Each dynCol In locArray
                
                If Not IsError(tableRow.Columns(i)) Then
                    If tableRow.Columns(i) = "" Then
                    FillCol tableRow.Columns(i), filePath, dynCol(0), dynCol(1)
                    'tableRow.Columns(i).Value = "='" & filePath & dynCol(0) & "'!" & dynCol(1)
                    End If
                End If
                
                i = i + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Sub FillCol(col, filePath, sheet, data)
    'col.Value = "=Index('" & filePath & sheet & "'!" & data & ",1,1)"
    col.Value = "='" & filePath & sheet & "'!" & data
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim course, recette, dossier, fichier, filePath As String` only declares `filePath` as a string.  Instead do: `Dim course As String, recette As String, dossier As String, fichier As String, filePath As String` and I bet the error will move to one of the lines where the values are assigned to the variable.  When that happens you need to look at the value in the cell and determine why it cannot be converted to a string.  It is probably an error.

Comment: If you're assigning formulas to a cell then `col.Formula` seems more appropriate.